# Move tag bubble out of the way on vertical lists of tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-bubble

It would be nice if the tag bubble showed up to the left of tags in cases where they are stacked vertically, like "Recent Tags" or "Unanswered Tags" in the sidebar. It's really annoying when I accidentally hover over the wrong one, because it blocks me from selecting the tags below it unless I move the mouse off in a different direction and wait for the bubble to disappear.

Here's an example of the problem, where the tags below [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) are hidden by the bubble:

[image]

Comment: btw does anyone else find this annoying ?